# How to get all b tag values from within class of html using php dom

Tags: php

i have html like this

```
<div class="panel panel-info" >
    <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 20px;" src="images/arrow.gif" alt="arrow" />
        <b>
            Click Here  all regions.
        </b>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 20px;" src="images/arrow.gif" alt="arrow" />
        <b>
            Click Here  all regions. 2
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" >
    <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 20px;" src="images/arrow.gif"  />
        <b>
            Click Here for3 .
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need to print all b tag values under spcific class called `class="panel panel-info"`

so

in php i am trying like this , but it is not working

```
    $urlContent = file_get_contents('http://hi.com');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($urlContent);
    $x = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $va = $x->query('//div[@class="panel panel-info"]/b');

    foreach ($va as $te) { 
        echo $te->textContent.'</br>';
    }
```

Comment: Try [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath was almost there, the problem is that when you use...

```
//div[@class="panel panel-info"]/b
```

the `/b` is saying you want the `<b>` element directly under the `<div>` element.  But there is another `<div>` element in between.  The most common way round this is to use `//` the same way you use it at the beginning to say you want a `<b>` tag anywhere under the `<div>` element

```
//div[@class="panel panel-info"]//b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="panel panel-info" >
    <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 20px;" src="images/arrow.gif" alt="arrow" />
        <b>
            Click Here  all regions.
        </b>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 20px;" src="images/arrow.gif" alt="arrow" />
        <b>
            Click Here  all regions. 2
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" >
    <div class="panel-heading" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img style="height: 10px; width: 20px;" src="images/arrow.gif"  />
        <b>
            Click Here for3 .
        </b>
    </div>
</div>';
$html_dom = new DOMDocument();
@$html_dom->loadHTML($html);
$x_path = new DOMXPath($html_dom);

$nodes= $x_path->query("//div[@class='panel-heading']");

foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
  foreach ($x_path->query('b', $node) as $child) {
        echo $child->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
die;?>
```

Comment: i need only class panel-info not  panel-heading class $nodes= $x_path->query("//div[@class='panel-heading']");

Answer (score 0):

Try [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
$urlContent = file_get_contents('http://hi.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($urlContent);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('b') as $te) { 
    echo $te->nodeValue.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: it all b tags we need to use class name to to target b tag